# Problems using jinja2 for code generation when using "include" to subsection contents

Tags: python, jinja2, code-generation

I am using an initial python script to pull together a json file and a .j2 (jinja2) file which outputs an executable second python script on runtime. The first python script works in the following way:

```
import json
from jinja2 import Template


json_file = "dag-input.json"
interface_file = "dag-template2.j2"


with open(interface_file) as template_f:
    interface_template = Template(template_f.read())

with open(json_file) as json_f:
    reader = json.load(json_f)
    interface_config = interface_template.render(
        **reader
    )

with open("output.py", "w") as python_f:
    python_f.write(interface_config)
```

Since my jinja template is very long. I would like to break it down into subsections, much like I have done before when creating HTML pages, using jinja 2 such like:

```
{% include 'task-templates/import.j2'%}
```

On runtime I get the following error. My question is: what additional configuration do I need to be able to use the jinja2 include feature in my case?

```
  **File "<template>", line 1, in top-level template code
TypeError: no loader for this environment specified**
```

As additional information, the error points to the following block of code as the initial source of the error:

```
interface_config = interface_template.render(
   **reader
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is that unless you are using a tool like Flask, the configuration of the environment needs to be done manually.

Essentially you can only access the templates that you wish to use with jinja2 include tags `{% include "my-template.j2" %}` if you have explicitly told the script where to look on render.

To do this add the following to the script:

```
from jinja2 import Template, Environment, FileSystemLoader

env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
template = env.get_template('dag-template.j2')
```

In such a way you are setting the root file as "." and the initial template to consider. From here you may use the include tags `{% include "my-template.j2" %}` within that initial template as you wish